# Graph theory meta-question

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

> If property (P) holds for perfect graphs and almost all graphs does it hold for all graphs?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood...  How about the property "G is perfect or has at least 20 vertices"? 

Comment: @Goldstern: Obviously this is not the kind of property I had in mind, but you have a good point there. I was thinking of things like Hadwiger's conjecture.

Comment: Take one non-perfect graph of each (large enough) order and define the property as being not equal to that chosen graph.  You need to work on your question a lot before it makes sense.

Comment: Or then again, take any property which have a finite number of exceptions, each of them a non perfect graph.

Comment: Would some sort of monotonicity (upwards or downwards) constraint on your property make this a meaningful question?